# Alternative options for scheduled job queue?

Tags: linux, scheduled-task, queue

I really like using queues for interprocess communication. It's great to be able to spin up a ton of workers and be guaranteed that a job in the queue is only run once, is treated fairly, can be scaled horizontally, and can optionally expire if it is not handled quickly enough.

However, I can't seem to find a job queue implementation that also supports putting jobs into the queue at a specified time.

What's the best way to attack this problem? Does a queue like this exist?

So far my alternatives to such a queue are:

1. beanstalkd - supports delayed jobs, I could calculate the delta between now and the specified time.

   - imprecise: what happens on timezone changes, or really large deltas (months)
2. "at" command - create an at job that would spin up and put the schedule job in a queue at the specified time.

   - tied to a single machine: What happens if the system restarts? How do you port jobs to a new server? Single point of failure
   - manually handle expiration if you have a long downtime.
3. delayed_job/custom polling - create a daemon (something like delayed_job) that continuously polls a database of scheduled jobs and inserts into queue at the specified time

   - seems too complicated

Answer (score 1):

Something like the [Open Source Job Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Job_Scheduler) may be appropriate...